# Error to install totalcross application

Tags: android

Error while installing the totalcross app on Android 4.3
I use totalcross 3 updated but previous version works.

The console show this error message:

```
here08-11 17:56:49.097: E/Parcel(596): Class not found when unmarshalling: com.android.packageinstaller.InstallFlowAnalytics
08-11 17:56:49.097: E/Parcel(596): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.packageinstaller.InstallFlowAnalytics
08-11 17:56:49.097: E/Parcel(596):  at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
08-11 17:56:49.097: E/Parcel(596):  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:251)
08-11 17:56:49.097: E/Parcel(596):  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:216)
08-11 17:56:49.097: E/Parcel(596):  at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2140)
08-11 17:56:49.097: E/Parcel(596):  at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2104)
08-11 17:56:49.097: E/Parcel(596):  at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2020)
08-11 17:56:49.097: E/Parcel(596):  at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2321)
08-11 17:56:49.097: E/Parcel(596):  at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:249)
08-11 17:56:49.097: E/Parcel(596):  at android.os.Bundle.getString(Bundle.java:1118)
08-11 17:56:49.097: E/Parcel(596):  at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:5046)
08-11 17:56:49.097: E/Parcel(596):  at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1595)
08-11 17:56:49.097: E/Parcel(596):  at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1238)
08-11 17:56:49.097: E/Parcel(596):  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerService.java:4068)
08-11 17:56:49.097: E/Parcel(596):  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivity(ActivityManagerService.java:3917)
08-11 17:56:49.097: E/Parcel(596):  at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:165)
08-11 17:56:49.097: E/Parcel(596):  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2654)
08-11 17:56:49.097: E/Parcel(596):  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
08-11 17:56:49.097: E/Parcel(596):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
08-11 17:56:49.097: E/Parcel(596): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/packageinstaller/InstallFlowAnalytics
08-11 17:56:49.097: E/Parcel(596):  ... 18 more
08-11 17:56:49.097: E/Parcel(596): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.android.packageinstaller.InstallFlowAnalytics" on path: DexPathList[[directory "."],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
08-11 17:56:49.097: E/Parcel(596):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
08-11 17:56:49.097: E/Parcel(596):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
08-11 17:56:49.097: E/Parcel(596):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
08-11 17:56:49.097: E/Parcel(596):  ... 18 more
```

Comment: In which device did this happened?

Comment: Samsung tab E Android 4.4.4

Comment: Does it install in another devices? Can you send me you apk?